# Rcpp compiler flags error with return value - clueless

Tags: r, rcpp

Im trying to speed up some R code with Rcpp functions.  One function is giving me fits to compile and I am clueless to figure out why the compiler complains about the return argument. I declared the function to return NumericVector, the result is NumericVector and yet the compiler complains the return argument is invalid.

Rcpp is version 0.12.18, 
R is Microsoft Open R 3.5.3

```
cppFunction('NumericVector NNE(IntegerVector X, IntegerVector Y, IntegerVector XY, IntegerVector xy, NumericVector P, int radius ) {

  int n = X.size();
  NumericVector vN[n];
  NumericVector vSum[n];
  NumericVector vAvg[n];


  // for each xy determine neighborhood Sum and count (N)
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    vN[i] = 0.0;
    vSum[i] = 0.0;

    // traverse neighborhood, if the xy exists in the input
    // vector then accumulate the values, otherwise ignore

    for(int dx=-1*radius; dx<=radius; dx++) {
      for(int dy=-1*radius; dy<=radius; dy++) {

        // construct an xy index for the neighborhood die
        xy[0] = ( (X[i]+dx) * 10000 ) + (Y[i]+dy);

        // check to see if index above exists in input set
        IntegerVector m = Rcpp::match(xy, XY);

        // if valid then accumulate and count
        if(m[0] != NA_INTEGER) {
          vN[i] = vN[i] + 1.0;
          vSum[i] = vSum[i] + P[ m[0] ];
        }
      }
    }

    vAvg[i] = vSum[i] / vN[i];
  }

  return vAvg;
}')
```

The confusing compiler message is as follows:

```
C:/RBuildTools/3.5/mingw_64/bin/g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~3/ROPEN~1/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"D:/Users/ka/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I"D:/Users/ka/AppData/Local/Temp/4/RtmpeGKfUg/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-0.12.18"   -I"C:/a/w/1/s/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c filefcc651c7fa9.cpp -o filefcc651c7fa9.o
filefcc651c7fa9.cpp: In function 'Rcpp::NumericVector NNE(Rcpp::IntegerVector, Rcpp::IntegerVector, Rcpp::IntegerVector, Rcpp::IntegerVector, Rcpp::NumericVector, int)':
filefcc651c7fa9.cpp:42:10: error: invalid conversion from 'Rcpp::NumericVector* {aka Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>*}' to 'const int&' [-fpermissive]
   return vAvg;
          ^
In file included from D:/Users/ka/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Vector.h:52:0,
                 from D:/Users/ka/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:40,
                 from filefcc651c7fa9.cpp:1:
D:/Users/ka/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:128:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>::Vector(const int&) [with int RTYPE = 14; StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]'
     Vector( const int& size ) {
     ^
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~3/ROPEN~1/R-35~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:215: filefcc651c7fa9.o] Error 1
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Comment: Can you add some sample inputs and expected results?

Comment: You are missing an earlier error.

Answer (score 4):

You had a *miniscule* error rendering *the variable* "bad" as far as the compiler is concerned, and you then misunderstood the rejected return of the "bad" variable as a different issue.

It happens. We have all been there.

Here is the repaired code. In short, you needed `NumeriVector x(n);` with *round*  instead of squared parens (as the latter denote arrays in C and then C++).

#### Code

I also turned it into input for `sourceCpp()` which is easier given the length of the functions.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector NNE(IntegerVector X, IntegerVector Y, IntegerVector XY,
                  IntegerVector xy, NumericVector P, int radius ) {

  int n = X.size();
  NumericVector vN(n);
  NumericVector vSum(n);
  NumericVector vAvg(n);

  // for each xy determine neighborhood Sum and count (N)
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    vN[i] = 0.0;
    vSum[i] = 0.0;

    // traverse neighborhood, if the xy exists in the input
    // vector then accumulate the values, otherwise ignore

    for(int dx=-1*radius; dx<=radius; dx++) {
      for(int dy=-1*radius; dy<=radius; dy++) {

        // construct an xy index for the neighborhood die
        xy[0] = ( (X[i]+dx) * 10000 ) + (Y[i]+dy);

        // check to see if index above exists in input set
        IntegerVector m = Rcpp::match(xy, XY);

        // if valid then accumulate and count
        if(m[0] != NA_INTEGER) {
          vN[i] = vN[i] + 1.0;
          vSum[i] = vSum[i] + P[ m[0] ];
        }
      }
    }

    vAvg[i] = vSum[i] / vN[i];
  }

  return vAvg;
}

/*** R
cat("Built\n")
*/
```

#### Output

As we have no reference data, I can only show that it built:

```
R> sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/61377960/answer.cpp")

R> cat("Built\n")
Built
R>
```

Comment: Hallelujah!  Dirk your help is most appreciated.  I bought your book 'Seamless R and C++ Integration w Rcpp' a few weeks ago and am thrilled by the performance boost Rcpp is providing.  Thank you for your prompt assistance and your endless contributions to the R community.

Comment: You are very welcome!  If only I had more time for updated 2nd edition ... Also, per StackOverflow convention (and, by the way, welcome to StackOverflow) feel free to "upvote" the answer (click on the upward triangle) and to "accept it" (click on the tickmark you as the original poster see).  That way kudos flows through the system, you too get some points for the act of accepting an answer.